# search string in varbinary column of SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I have a table which has 3 columns:

- ProblemID
- FileContent
- FileName

I want to search for a user specified string from the `fileContent` column. Is it possible to convert binary data in `VARCHAR`? I tried it but it gives results in different format.
i am storing .pdf files only

Comment: For what database?  Varbinary suggests SQL Server...

Comment: full text index: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142531.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't search real binary data in SQL Server if the binary format is Word or Excel or anything except a raw text file